# Оставить только строки, начинающиеся на.. Notepad++

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Есть текстовый файл. В нем есть разные строки, но нужно оставить только строки вида:

```
(01)54662030989(21)Dp>s9P
(01)04606203098910(2!i9jmwf
```

Тоесть оставить все строки начинающиеся с (01)

Как это сделать в Notepad++ ?

Comment: ну то есть что тут пригодятся регулярные выражние вам понятно. Так сделайте же шаг вперед и освойте хотя бы азы этого полезного инструмента.

Comment: `^(?!\(01\)).+$` заменить на ничто. останутся пустые строки, их потом подчистите